# How to get json array value into J2ME

Tags: arrays, json, java-me

**`[{"customer_id":"12345","username":"admin","role":"1","userid":"001","status":SUCCESS"}]`**

How to get `Json` `Array` value in `J2ME`

Comment: You can use `json` library for that. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981296/json-parser-for-j2me

Comment: i need to get Http Request Data which is comes in Json array format how to get array values

Answer (score 0):

1st of all minor mistake in the string posted..it shd be

[{\"customer_id\":\"12345\",\"username\":\"admin\",\"role\":\"1\",\"userid\":\"001\",\"status\":\"SUCCESS\"}]

You can download the following files for json Parsing..Use them in your project

**http://grt192.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CannonBot/src/org/json/me/**

Try the following code

```
    try {
        JSONArray tmparr = new JSONArray(response);
        JSONObject tmpobj = new JSONObject(tmparr.getString(0));
        System.out.println("custid " + tmpobj.get("customer_id"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Nitin jain.. First of all thank you for reply as i submitted my code above can you please tell me about how to add json files into my project as am working in netbeans i want to save array values into client end so please suggest me right way for getting these values Thank You.. Peace .. :)