# Built-in JSON parser in J2ME?

Tags: json, java-me

I'm developing an application (MIDlet) for the Gemalto EHS6 modem, which runs java micro edition. I want to make an HTTP post using the JSON format. What would be the easiest way to do this?

`org.json` is not supported in J2ME

I've already read [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981296/json-parser-for-j2me), but I can't believe that would be the way to do it!? Depend on some 3rd party implementation? I could write a simply one myself only for the subset of the JSON format I need - But this does not seem like the "right" choice. Or what? Is that the most efficient way of doing it in the end?

Comment: As far as I know there is no plan to add built-in support for Json on J2ME. But you may try using/porting https://jsonp.java.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an API for JSON in Java ME. You can see it in the section [Oracle Java ME Embedded APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/javame-apis.htm), the package name for that is `com.oracle.json`. It is available since the 8.0 release.

The main problem for you is that the modem you mentioned supports only Java ME 3.2 judging by its web page. Unless you know a way to upgrade it to the 8.0 release or higher, I'm afraid you're stuck with using your own libraries.

Comment: Great answer! In my case, however, I don't know if I could/should do that. The modem runs a lot of firmware from Gemalto, providing security and maintenance - so an upgrade would probably leave me without their support.